# Trigger old camera flash

Tags: arduino

I have an old camera flash that I want to trigger using my Arduino and an optoisolator. The flash has two wires.  When they are connected, the flash is triggered

How can I connect it to the optoisolator?

Comment: @opc0de - I understand that English might not be your first language.  I don't know Romanian, but one of the basic rules of English is that separate thoughts, known as *clauses*, are separated by punctuation and conjunction into *sentences*.  Your first sentence continued into your second and third sentence. This is known as a 'run-on sentence', and it's difficult to read.  I've corrected the problem.  Also, please *always* capitalize the word "I": regardless of it's prevalence in online chats or SMS messages, it's wrong and unprofessional to write 'i'. I have fixed your question.

Comment: Related: [Interfacing an optoisolator with an Arduino](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/26213/interfacing-an-optoisolator-with-arduino)

Comment: I removed my downvote of this question now that @Kevin has fixed it.  Non-native english speakers get a little slack, but your languages have sentences too, so there was no excuse for the runon "sentence".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Olin says, flashes can have very high voltages across the trigger contacts.

If you volate is less than about 300 CV (less than 350 if you are brave) then the
[MOC8204 SM 400V optocoupler](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/4N%2F4N38M.pdf) may work OK.
 This costs [$1.25 in stock in 1's at Digikey](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/dksearch/dksus.dll?KeywordSearch).

It is rated at 100 mA max in the output circuit.
 Measure the output voltage as Olin suggests.
 Take a resistor R > Vmeasured x 20
 eg if Vmeasure = 300V use a resistor of at least 300 x 2= = 6000 ohms.
 Connect this resistor across the flash contacts.
 If this resistor reliably fires the flash then the optocoupler (probably) will too.

Collector, pin 5 to flash +ve.
 Emitter, pin 4 to flsah -ve.
 Cathode, pin 2 to Arduino ground.
 esistor to pin 1 from Arduino = on signal **BUT** Arduino will probably not have anough drive.

You will probably need a transistor to allow the Arduino to drive this opto - as you will also need if you use a relay.

More anon mayhaps.

Agh again: This is less suitable than it appeared but MAY work OK. You need to know what resistance will trigger the flash. The opto has a 100 mA max output current rating BUT the LED cannot support enoughdrive to provide 100 mA. Very strange specs.

Answer (score 6):

Camera flashes, especially old ones, may have significant voltage accross their switch terminals when the switch is open.  Let it charge up and measure between the two lines with a voltmeter.  It could be surprisingly high, easily higher than the average opto-isolator.

Next you have to consider the current requirements when the switch is closed.  Again, that can vary considerably between flashes.  Modern "electronic" flashes have a low open circuit voltage and require low current to close the connection.  That is because this is a signal into other circuitry that actually initiates the flash.  Old flashes were much simpler, and the camera was assumed to have a mechanical switch closure to trigger them.  This switch more directly triggered the flash, so could be nearly 200V open and a sudden burst of current when closed.  Both these specs would be well beyond most opto-isolators.

I recommend that instead of using a opto, have the microcontroller activate a relay.  Wire the flash trigger leads to the normally open relay contacts and it should work fine for all types of flashes.

Comment: +1 for the relay.  Sometimes still just the best choice, especially when mimicking an existing switch.